# inplace_merge : why isn't inplace_merge merging the strings?

Tags: c++

Why isn't `inplace_merge` merging the strings in the code below?

```
string src = "abc";
string new_str = "def";
src += new_str;
inplace_merge(src.begin(), src.begin()+3, src.end());
cout << src; // abcdef
```

Edit: I expected "adbecf"

Comment: The result of the merge is always an ordered sequence, so you should expect obtaining what you get, the string ordered as `"abcdef"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work properly, but you have chosen bad test data.

[`std::inplace_merge`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge) does a merge on two sorted consecutive ranges in a sequence, **like in a merge sort**.

That is, if you pass the string `adebcf` (supposing the parameters are set as in your question), it will be merged into `abcdef`. 
If you pass a string `abcdef`, the result is the same as the input, because this string is already in order.